# I want to create a file named "Grocery List" (2 words in the name of this file)

Tags: files, filenames, cat

I do know that we can use

```
cat > fire
```

to make a file with the name "fire". But if the name of the file contains 2 words like "Grocery list", how does one make that?

Since

```
cat > Grocery list
```

gives the weird message `cat: list: No such file or directory`.

Please help me out.

Comment: Also beware that `>` will overwrite the file; if you want to add more lines (append), use `>>` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Many ways:

- Using single quotes around name:

  ```
  cat > 'Grocery list'
  ```
- Using double quotes around name:

  ```
  cat > "Grocery list"
  ```
- Escape the whitespace with `\`:

  ```
  cat > Grocery\ list
  ```

---

When you do:

```
cat > Grocery list
```

`Grocery` and `list` are taken as two words.

The output direction `> Grocery` is done by shell, and it happens first, so the file `Grocery` is created, and then `cat list` is run i.e. `list` is taken as an argument to `cat`, as presumably there is no file as `list` present in the current directory, hence the error about missing `list` file.

So, in this case, essentially you are doing:

```
cat list > Grocery
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the space somehow. heemayl's given you a good answer, but I recommend reading this one for details also: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

As for creating the file itself, you don't need to use `cat`.

```
> file
```

is enough.